# After a VLOOKUP formula, the value it finds gets rounded up

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The problem I've found is:

The `VLOOKUP` function finds a value on another sheet, **which is excatly 36.5**.
But in the table where the function is, **it represents 37**.

There is no rounding up in any function at all, so I'm not quite sure what makes it bad.

Here is the formula I have:

```
=VLOOKUP(Main!$C28;table!$G:$BH;21;0)
```

Comment: Check cell formatting. Make cell formatting decimal place 2 digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While cell formatting on the source table does not matter, the cell formatting **does** matter very much on the cell with the `VLOOKUP` function.

Highlight the cell with the `VLOOKUP` and tap <kbd>CTRL+1</kbd> to bring up the Format Cells box. Should be set to `Number` with the desired number of decimal places.